# Taylor Polynomial of $f(x)=\cos(x)\cdot\sin(x)$

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

How would I calculate the third maclaurin/taylor polynomial on $\cos(a) \cdot \sin(b)$, Do I use the product rule when I calculate the derivatives? I don't know where to start or read about it, been stuck for a couple of days now. Thank you!

Comment: If you write $\sin x\cos x=\frac{1}{2}\sin(2x)$, then you don't even need the product rule.

Comment: It was actually cos(a)*sin(b), can you still help me?

Comment: You know the rule how to calculate the derivatives, and you know the general formula of Taylor polynoms... Please, explain, where do you see obstacles that prevents you from solving this task on your own?

Comment: @r4sk3n Considering your typo, perhaps you should put a new post AND show us your findings. Have you by the way heard of a product to sum formula?

Comment: @imranfat No I have not, I will check it out!

Comment: @r4sk3n did you understand my solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easieast way was pointed out by Kim Jong Un in the comment, but there are a couple of other ways to do that. Remember that the $n$-th degree McLaurin polynomial is

$$T_n(x) = \sum_{i=0}^n f^{(n)}(0) \frac{x^n}{n!}$$

But if $f(x) = \sin (x) \cos (x)$ then $f'(x) = \cos^2 (x) - \sin^2(x)$, $f''(x) = -4\sin(x)\cos(x)$ and $f'''(x) =  -4(
\cos^2 (x) - \sin^2(x))$

Then, $f(0) = 0$, $f'(0) = 1$, $f''(0)=0$, $f'''(0)=-4$

So $$T_3(x) = x -\frac{2}{3}x^3$$